# Can two (or more) jpeg2000 be combined into one bigger one without decoding them to bitmap?

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, jpeg2000

I have four .j2k files (loseless) of known identical size and I want to combine them into one bigger .j2k file. Now of course the simple and working way is to decompress them into bitmap and compress the larger bitmap to .j2k file - but that is performance costly. Is there a simpler way ? And if so can you highlight it in pseudocode ?

**UPDATE**

Based on @malat suggestion I tried following [(see my github repo for full sources and image examples)](https://github.com/svejdo1/Jpeg2000/):

```
// for the simplicity I'm using same image to make 4 tiles 2x2
jpeg.header.Xsiz *= 2;
jpeg.header.Ysiz *= 2;
vector<j2k_tile_part> tiles = jpeg.tiles;

BOOST_FOREACH(j2k_tile_part& part, jpeg.tiles)
{
    part.Isot = 2;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(const j2k_tile_part& part, tiles)
    {
        j2k_tile_part clone(part);
        switch(i)
        {
        case 0:
            clone.Isot = 3;
            break;
        case 1:
            clone.Isot = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            clone.Isot = 1;
            break;
        }
        jpeg.tiles.push_back(clone);
    }
}

jpeg.save_file(output_file);
```

Which works (in terms of image having correct size and being filled with image data). It looks OK only for first tile, but other tiles are screwed up. I though the tiles are encoded separately - am I wrong ? I also tried copying COD and QCC markers from main header to tile header - but that didn't helped either.

[image: Combined image]

Comment: You need to give more details on what you want in the end: JP2 Part-1 only or Part-2 acceptable (ex: JPX file) ? Are all tiles identical size ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. Just start it backward. Let's assume your target image is 512x512 and each of your 4 tiles (J2K input) are each 256x256. In which case let's create a fake (but valid) JP2 file equivalent:

```
$ wget http://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lena512color.tiff
$ kdu_compress -i lena512color.tif -o out.jp2 Stiles="{256,256}"  Clevels:T0C1=0  Cuse_sop:T3=yes  Cycc:T2=no
```

Do not worry too much about `Clevels:T0C1=0  Cuse_sop:T3=yes  Cycc:T2=no`, they are only useful to make sure that `COC` and `QCC` are produced after the `COD` and `QCD` from the main header.

Now that you have a valid JP2 container (format) you simply need to replace each individual tiles (valid J2K codestream) with your (there should be 4 of them).

Another important thing is to check that all codestream have a proper `SOT length`. Remember that it is legal to have a SOT length of zero (undefined length) only for the very last tile.

If you want to go further, you will need to make sure that:

- Try to re-use `QCD` and `COD` if your image have identical parameters (I have assumed they were somewhat different)
- Add `TLM` markers

Comment: the JPEG 2000 codestream you used is a bit special. In your code you are removing COC and QCC which make the decoding fails later on. Simply pick a simplier JPEG 2000 codestream (your code is working for me, see update images at: https://github.com/malaterre/Jpeg2000)

Comment: I believe I've used wrong indexes for tiles; which is now all set; still the combined image looks ok only for first tile. Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I've uploaded a working JP2 sample: https://github.com/malaterre/Jpeg2000/commit/052eb26c00832720426da3b85354f16bc1594c7a

Comment: thank you for that; when I analyze your Bretagne1024.j2p, there are four tiles, but they have different size/content (for example first tile has size of bitstream 106 766, second tile has size of bitstream 106 821 and they're physically different from bitstream index 791 (dec)) - I though your original premise was we can just replace tile "placeholders" with our content; however it seems the content of tiles (T2/T3/T4) is physically different.